# JWT verification of signature on each page?

Tags: server, jwt, client, signature

I am fairly new to JWT and I need to implement it. We use angular on client and PHP with composer on backend. I already know basics on verification and token forming. So I can form the token and sign it on server side, then send it to cient side for saving in a `localStorage` or somewhere similar. My question is, on subsequent requests of browser for some page, do I need to check the signature? Seems to be like I do, since merely checking the existence of token on client-side doesn't do much. Please advise? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Once the Jwt is stored on the client side, on every request made to the server, it has to be checked and verified before serving the page requested.
If the token doesn't exists, the client needs to be authenticated.   If the token exists but doesn't match the signature, the client needs to get a new one, so it needs to re-authenticate.

So token verification is mandatory each time you have to pass through the server.